# Regex to extract a JSON object embeded within XML string

Tags: javascript, regex, json, xml, d3.js

I am working on a JS & D3 project that requires JSON data, and the service I must use transfers said data as JSON inside an XML string like so...

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
[

{"Wonderful JSON" : "in here."}

]
</string>
```

Would anyone save me a little time and show me the regex that would give me just the `{"Wonderful JSON" : "in here."}` without the array brackets or the xml markup, and in a non-hacky way?

Comment: You should first parse the XML (or handle it using any DOM available) and then extract the node value. Do not use regex for that... Are you handling this XML in javascript?

Answer (score -1):

This regex should work

```
/\{(.*?)\}/g
```